# How to auto Archive by version history

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, version, sharepoint-2013, history

I want to put the files from Document library A into another document library called Archive. I have to version history enabled, limited to 10. when a new file gets added in, the older files get deleted. How can I move them to another document library called Archive. How can I achieve this? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Using MS Flow you can build a simple workflow that will copy a file from one library to another one. The workflow can be triggered upon file add (list item) event. Everything can be done in MS Flow browser designer. When adding file to archive library you need to change its file name (e.g. add time stamp) so you will not overwrite existing file in archive library.